# can we use hard disk space for jvm memory

Tags: java, memory

Can we give heap memory more than physical ram on system to Java process.

Example. 
system has 8 gb ram.
Operating system consumes let's say 2 gb ram
We start Java process1 and allocate 4 gb ram
We start Java process2 and allocate 4 gb ram

If space in ram is not available, then Java process uses hard disk cache for saving unused part of programmatically in memory.

Comment: it would be terribly slow

Comment: For me currently it's okay if it's slow... is it possible to do it?

Comment: It's called "swapping" and it's been a standard feature of OSs since forever.

Comment: I just tried "new"ing non-managed memory area from a dll and writing to 2x 1G float arrays, once 8GB reached HDD usage went to %100 and mouse+task-monitor froze until I hard reset.

Comment: a JVM is like any other program so yes it is possible as the memory allocation is managed by your OS and your OS can swap

Comment: What configuration are required to enable swapping of Java process memory

Comment: @sam_evang Normally nothing, unless you disabled your [OS pagefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Windows_NT), though you may also need to increase the pagefile size if you're going to overload your memory a lot. How do manage the pagefile depends on your OS.

Comment: Note that the (virtual) memory used by a JVM process is more than the configured heap size, by anywhere from maybe 10MB to hundreds of MB or more. Once you start swapping significantly, expect programs to take at least several times longer, often 100 or 1000 times.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should remember that -Xmx setting is not whole memory which JVM allocates. It's just size of the heap (space for objects) and some more space also will be allocated. For -Xmx4G whole memory allocation can be for example 5Gb.
2. You can swap JVM memory into disk, but then your JVM will be really slow. Garbage collector during memory cleanup often needs to scan whole memory (even very rarely used regions) so it will be swapping a lot during GC cycles.

Comment: Today we can safely assume SSD which is quite good at reading, at least 500 MB/s. Server-class goes way beyond 1 GB/s.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It's RW access not read-only. And modern RAM can handle more than 10GB/s so the difference is huge.

Comment: Realistically it will be less than 10 GB/s due to all the pointer chasing and branch mispredictions. And 10x slower is still not a huge difference given the general expectations of what swapping does to performance.